# Recover LVM setup by reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: lvm

If I have a LVM set up on my "data" disks, will reinstalling Ubuntu on the OS disk allow me to recover the original LVM set up?

I'm slightly worried that I won't be able to see any data on my disks after a reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you must to be careful on setting up the disks during the (re)install.

Comment: OK, specifically what must I do?  What traps must I avoid?  "Be careful" is far to generic to be helpful.